# HDD in pre-fail? What you can say to me?

Tags: hard-drive, smart

I have a Seagate Barracuda ST2000DM006 with this SMART result:

```
$ sudo smartctl -A /dev/sda
[sudo] senha para daniel:        
smartctl 7.2 2020-12-30 r5155 [x86_64-linux-6.2.0-26-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-20, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 10
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   118   099   006    Pre-fail  Always       -       168960448
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0003   096   096   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   098   098   020    Old_age   Always       -       2299
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000f   075   060   030    Pre-fail  Always       -       40827758
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   092   092   000    Old_age   Always       -       7619
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   098   098   020    Old_age   Always       -       2124
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0032   100   100   099    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0 0 0
189 High_Fly_Writes         0x003a   096   096   000    Old_age   Always       -       4
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0022   070   060   045    Old_age   Always       -       30 (Min/Max 18/30)
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       48
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   088   088   000    Old_age   Always       -       25872
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   030   040   000    Old_age   Always       -       30 (0 11 0 0 0)
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0010   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x003e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
240 Head_Flying_Hours       0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       6004h+53m+31.586s
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       26758894512
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       192651057769
```

How long do you think this HDD will last? How long should I have before I have to buy another HDD? I think I bought it before 2013.

Comment: The drive is old and there is nothing more to say. It could last a month or it could last 5 more years. The only way to know is to use it and find out.

Comment: backup your data NOW.

Comment: I see no failures./errors. Don't be fooled by large RAW values. That said, the drive is old but no one can tell when the drive will fail. You're asking for opinion based answers basically.

Answer (score 2):

Too many failures in my view.

I suggest you replace the Hard Drive right away and do not wait for it to fail.

Begin backing it up right away.

Comment: I don’t see too many failures? Seagate SMART data often looks far worse than it is. But the drive is old so probably best to replace anyway

Comment: How every we define too many (I clarified my post), I replaced such drives right away.

Comment: To @Daniel - FWIW I have a decade old X230 ThinkPad in my basement (running all the time) with a 500 GB Hitachi Hard Drive. Lenovo Diagnostics report 0 errors on the drive.

Comment: Errors are the column THRESH?

Comment: I did not see errors there. The drive has about 42,000 hours on it,